# Passing Jquery Array to PHP script through Confirm window via ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have looked through all of the suggested answers and duplicates, but I am not seeing what I am missing. From the various solutions I have seen, this *should* work.

I am passing a jQuery array of sample names to a PHP script via Ajax when the user clicks OK on the confirm popup. (The confirm box is triggered when the user uses a shift-select zoom method, which in turn pushes the sample names found inside the zoom box into the download_list variable.)

Except that it doesn't seem to be calling my PHP script when the user clicks OK.

The PHP script loops over the input names and creates a series of files in a zip archive. But trying to pass it the data via this method isn't going so well.

**console.log of download_list example**

```
["b01", "1._s16", "2._s17", "3._s18 ", "4._s19", "5._s20", "6._s21", "s01", "s02", "s03", "s04", "s05", "s06", "s08", "s09", "s10", "s11", "s14", "s17", "s18"]
```

**jQuery**

```
map.on("boxzoomend", function(e) {
    var download_list = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < bulk_list.length; i++) {
        if (e.boxZoomBounds.contains(bulk_list[i].latlng)) {
            download_list.push(bulk_list[i].name);
        }
    }
    if (confirm("Download the microbial community data for the following samples:" + download_list.toString())) { //alert("Download Beginning");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "zip_download.php",
            data: {download_list: download_list}
        });

    } else {}
});
```

**PHP**

```
$sample_name_list = $_REQUEST['download_list'];

echo ($sample_name_list);
```

Comment: So the php is not receiving any data? try a simple string. I doubt an array can be sent like this. You may have to json.stringify() it and add headers to ajax for proper datatype and context.

Answer (score 0):

In your Jquery AJAX method what is test in data Object? you should pass download_list variable

```
       $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "zip_download.php",
        data: {download_list: download_list}
    });
```

And by the way you can check if your ajax working by monitoring http requests in Network section of Inspector of your Browser.

Comment: Sorry, that was an artifact from trying to pass different data sets this way.  It doesn't work with it set to download_list either.

Answer (score 0):

In the php file, you're looking for the `$_REQUEST` with an key `download_list`

In your ajax function, the `data` is `{key:value}` but you don't have `test` as a valid value. Change the line to be:

`data: {download_list: download_list}`

Comment: Sorry, that was an artifact from trying to pass different data sets this way.  It doesn't work with it set to download_list either.